# associate a fixed private ip address on gcp compute machine with terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

i have this terraform to use to assign a static private ip address to a new machine
i run this terraform but i still see

> Error: Error creating instance: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value
> for field 'resource.networkInterfaces[0].networkIP':
> '192.168.128.206'. IP address
> 'projects/prj-xxxxx/regions/europe-xxx/addresses/demo-xxxx-nodoa-c'
> (192.168.128.206') is reserved by another project., invalid

this i the code used

```
resource "google_compute_address" "static-ip" {
  for_each     = toset(var.zones)
  name         = "${local.infra_id}-nodoa-${each.key}"
  project      = var.host_project.project_id
  address_type = "INTERNAL"
  region       = var.region
  purpose    = "GCE_ENDPOINT"
  subnetwork         = var.host_project.nodoa_subnet_name

}


resource "google_compute_instance" "nodoa" {
  for_each     = toset(var.zones)
  project      = var.service_project.project_id
  name         = "${local.infra_id}-nodoa-${each.key}"
  hostname     = "${local.infra_id}-nodoa-${each.key}.${local.subdomain}"
  machine_type = "xxx"
  zone         = "${var.region}-${each.key}"
  network_interface {
    subnetwork         = var.host_project.nodoa_subnet_name
    subnetwork_project = var.host_project.project_id
    network_ip = google_compute_address.static-ip[each.key].address
  }
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = var.rhcos_gcp_image
      size  = var.install_config_params.disk_size
      type  = "pd-ssd"
    }
    kms_key_self_link = ecr
  }
```

Comment: the error message seems to tell you exactly what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

@cava cavamagie I guess you need to specify 'network_ip' block inside access_config block.

```
access_config {
    nat_ip = google_compute_address.static-ip[each.key].address
}
```

So in general your resource block for "google_compute_instance" should look like below

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "nodoa" {
  for_each     = toset(var.zones)
  project      = var.service_project.project_id
  name         = "${local.infra_id}-nodoa-${each.key}"
  hostname     = "${local.infra_id}-nodoa-${each.key}.${local.subdomain}"
  machine_type = "xxx"
  zone         = "${var.region}-${each.key}"
  network_interface {
    subnetwork         = var.host_project.nodoa_subnet_name
    subnetwork_project = var.host_project.project_id
    access_config {
    nat_ip = google_compute_address.static-ip[each.key].address
}
  }
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = var.rhcos_gcp_image
      size  = var.install_config_params.disk_size
      type  = "pd-ssd"
    }
    kms_key_self_link = ecr
  }
```

Reference : [How to map static IP to terraform google compute engine instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45359189/how-to-map-static-ip-to-terraform-google-compute-engine-instance)

Comment: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance  the network_ip is under network_interface https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance#network_ip

Comment: @cavacavamagie if you closely look at my answer, you shall get details. I have mentioned you have to use 'network_ip' inside access_config. access_config block will be there inside network_interface. I have mentioned complete 'resource' block, I guess you can use same. Let me know if this helps!! P.S : Terraform registry link which you shared has 'access_config' block inside network_interface block

Comment: but i receive : Error: Unsupported argument

  on masters.tf line 31, in resource "google_compute_instance" "master":
  31:     network_ip = google_compute_address.static-ip[each.key].address

An argument named "network_ip" is not expected here.

Comment: @cavacavamagie try to change name of 'network_ip' to 'nat_ip' and give a try, something like this.... nat_ip = google_compute_address.static-ip[each.key].address. I have updated my answer, please take a look